# Lost all Jobs inbox messages after changing login method

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, merge-accounts, jobs-messages

I previously used my Facebook account to login to Stack Overflow, and now I have just changed to my Gmail account.

The changing process is finished, I received an Email Verification, but all my Jobs messages are lost.

[image: Inbox message]

I can see the brief message when clicking to Inbox icon but when I go to the message detail, the links seem to be broken or unavailable to me.

[image: Inbox message]

Can you guys help me look into this case? I really want to see the previous Jobs messages, it's really important to me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

There's a short but helpful [FAQ article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) which solved a similar sounding problem for me recently (split accounts) where a merge was the solution.
When you fill the [support form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) there is a readymade selection in the category dropdown: *"I need to merge user profiles*".

As long as you have sufficient evidence (e.g. same e-mail registered with both accounts) the support can merge the accounts for you. It also helps to briefly tell what kind of stuff went missing (like the job messages) in order to have a successful merge.